# I want to open a new tab and immediatly run a function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want the user to have a selection between multiple links/buttons.

Each button opens the same new tab, however depending on which button you pressed before, the new webpage should run a different function.

Is that possible?

Comment: Sure you may. In jquery, you can use the `each()` method as one of many options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright then, I guess I will try to write it.

You can attach a unique text to the url each time you load that same page using one of the buttons.

For example, you will have 3 links for those pages.

```
<a href="index.html?firstLink" target="_blank">Click me</a>

<a href="index.html?secondLink" target="_blank">Click me</a>

<a href="index.html?thirdLink" target="_blank">Click me</a>
```

This is the whole HTML part. Now to JavaScript.

In JS, you simply have to catch your current `url`.

You can do this by using `window.location.href`.

Next what you need to do is to split the `url` string on `?` sign.

This will return an array of 2 elements (for example, first element will be `index.html`, and the second one would be `firstLink`).

Now all you have to do is store the second value of that array into a variable, and just make a bunch of `if` statements with different functions based on what your `url` contains.

Here is HTML example code :

```
<a href="index.html?first" target="_blank">link 1</a>

<a href="index.html?second" target="_blank">link 2</a>

<a href="index.html?third" target="_blank">link 3</a>
```

Here is JS example code :

```
let url = window.location.href;

let splitIt = url.split('?');

console.log(splitIt)

let getWord = splitIt[1];

if(getWord == 'first'){

    alert('radi');

}

if(getWord == 'second'){

    alert('radi i ovo');

}
```